# Clear transform of control armature bones does not reset deform armature bones

Tags: rigging, armature, transforms

I have a deform armature, with another separate control armature for the rigging and posing.
The control armature has IKs, Spline IK etc., and it does work to control the deform armature.

For the neck and base of the tail (the model is of a large felid), I have bones in the control armature that match the position of the deform bones, and I have a "Copy transform" bone constraint set up so that the deform bones follow the motions of the control bones.

This does work - but when I want to reset the positions of those bones, when I select the control bones for the neck and tail base, and choose "clear pose transform", the control bones are re-set to the default position, but the corresponding/matching deform bones ARE NOT and remain in the transformed position.

Does anyone know a way to fix this, and to reset both sets of bones?
I could reset the bones in the control armature then go in separately and reset the bones in the deform armature, but this would be more slow and not very pleasant as workflow.

Does anyone have any tips for this?

Comment: Could you add some images, or upload a blend file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's ok actually, I changed the constraint from "copy transform" to IK control instead, and this seemed to resolve the problem. I'm not entirely sure what caused the issue the first time around, but switching this to IK and "use tail" ticked seemed to fix it.

Comment: instead of marking the question as "Solved" please write an answer to your own question and mark that as accepted. Otherwise your question is still considered as unanswered... please read: [Can I answer my own question?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and also the links on this page to understand how this site works: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Ah, thank you for this - I will fix that now. (still new to how this site works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I changed the control set up so that the deform armature bone constraints were changed to "inverse kinematics" rather than "copy transform" - I do not understand how exactly, but this appeared to resolve the issue.