# How can I copy the Armature Rest Position into an initial Pose Position (Clear Pose does nothing)

Tags: rigify, pose-mode

I want to copy the Rest Position into a Pose Position.  I cannot find a way to accomplish this.

I have a character ("DazToBlender" add-on, import from DAZ Studio, Rigified) where the default Pose Position has a caved-in chest area (after I click the Rigify button after import).

[image]

As you'll see, the Rest Position looks desirable, and being able to set this as my default/initial Pose Position would simplify trying to straighten out the armature post otherwise.   Select all Alt-G etc to clear transforms doesn't work.

[image]

[image] file attached.

Comment: Thanks, @batFINGER -- but I've edited my Q to mention that "Select all, Cear Transforms (All, Rotation, Positon)" doesn't work.  I included the (reduced) blend file that demonstrates this.

Comment: Not mentioned as a fix, mentioned re comparing the poses. Haven't DL'd but to my "spot the difference"  eye pose vs rest pose are different above (forget the mesh). Inquiring if pose above is all zero, and if applicable in FK mode.

Comment: Or to put another way in REST POSE the bones are locked to edit locations. So (IK, a usual suspect) and other  keyframes / constraints / drivers don't move anything.  Often difficult to fix. Anyhoo someone will surely download and have a closer look.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96011/how-to-set-rest-pose-as-pose   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72155/clear-transform-of-control-armature-bones-does-not-reset-deform-armature-bones

Comment: Have you edited/customized the rig? The issue are the upper spine bones. Usually, DEF-spine.002 is connected to DEF-spine.003 and DEF-spine.001. But in your rig the 002 and 003 overlap and have an offset & are not connected. I guess, the IK/MCH bones/contraints kick in (in Pose mode) and can move the bone in way they usually can't. There are also gaps between shoulder, elbows, and neck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's looking like a [known bug](https://github.com/daz3d/DazToBlender/issues/44) in the Rigify code of the DazToBlender add-on.   However, I'm still interested to see if there's a way to correct this in blender, as the Rest Pose looks correct.